# How to reproduce MATCHES in NSPredicate to query Realm?

Tags: regex, nspredicate, realm

I have a query using `NSPredicate` that takes regular expression and matches to paths:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "path MATCHES '/test/([^/]*[^/])$'")
```

which matches everything inside folder **test** but excludes all subfolders of folders in **test**, like this:

1. /test/abc -> *yes*
2. /test/abc/def -> *no*

The problem is, that I can't use the `MATCH` keyword of `NSPredicate` in **Realm.io**. How can I reproduce this query so it works in Realm?

Adding the exception for completeness:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid operator type', reason: 'Operator type 6 not supported for string type'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for now I have solved the problem like this (modifying the model, which I wanted to avoid):

1. I store only the path to the parent, not the full one along with the name. The name gets stored in a different field (to get full path I stitch the two strings together)
2. Instead of matching the regular expression I use `NSPredicate(format: "path ==[c] %@", "/test/")` to get the contents of the folder *test*.

**Why am I not totally happy with this solution:**

I wanted to avoid separating the field *fullPath* into two fields because when file gets renamed + moved, it's only one operation - rewrite the *fullPath* in the database. It may seem like a minor problem, but having only one place of responsibility gave it a bit more robustness, because files are moved and renamed all the time in the environment of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Joe from Realm here. Currently regex isn't supported in Realm queries with `MATCH`, you will need to do this manually. I would build an NSArray and use a filter predicate on that. We are aware of this and tracking all unsupported predicates [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1490)

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your time. However I was able to get this information in https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMQueryUtil.mm lines **685-706**. I hoped you would know of some workaround.

Comment: Problem solved by changing the model. Proposed `NSArray` filtering was unacceptable - in case of large number of subfolders and files I was literally cycling through the whole structure twice when listing contents of the root folder. Keeping close eye on **#1490** :-)

Comment: Glad to hear you found a better alternative solution! Thanks for being so patient as we continue to add more support for querying